# How to speed up Pandas read_sql from Oracle DB using threads?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy, parquet

I'd like to optimize **querying and converting a list of Oracle tables into pandas dataframes**.

The eventual goal is to convert to Parquet, write to disk, then upload to S3, but for now I just want to focus on the **pandas / sqlalchemy / parallelism** part.

My code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def process_chunk(chunk, table_name, index):
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk)
    local_file_name = "./" + table_name + "-" + str(index) + ".parquet"
    pq.write_table(table, local_file_name)

def process_table(table):
    db_session = DBSession()
    # helper function that creates the SQL query (select col1, col2, col3, ..., colX from table)
    query = setup_query(table)
    i=0
    # is this the right way to use the db_session?
    for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, db_session.bind, chunksize=300000):
        process_chunk(chunk, table, i)
        i+=1

oracle_connect_str = #string_here#
oracle_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    oracle_connect_str,
    arraysize=10000
)

# set up session object to be used by threads
DBSession = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        autoflush=True,
        autocommit=False,
        bind=oracle_engine
    )
)

pool = ThreadPool(4)

table_list = ['tbl1','tbl2','tbl3','tbl4','tbl5',...,'tbl20']

# use pool.map instead of creating boiler-plate threading class
pool.map(process_table, table_list)

# are these in the right spots?
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

It sort of works, but it's very slow and seems to hang after completing 10 tables.

Any advice for speeding things up? Alternative suggestions?

Happy to explain more with what's going on in the code if it helps.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Not really. The code has improved since I asked this (using fewer threads, dealing with db timeouts, etc.), but it's still slow.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update the code?